# How do you configure auditd logs to show up in journalctl?

Tags: audit, journalctl

I cannot find the usual auditd logs when doing "journalctl | grep msg=audit". However, I do see the auditd logs in /var/log/audit/audit.log and when doing ausearch. Is there a way to configure it so that the auditd logs show up in journalctl as well? Thanks.

Comment: See here: https://major.io/2017/01/05/display-auditd-messages-with-journalctl/